# Does the White Tanooki Suit work the same in the Special worlds?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

I finished the main story of Super Mario 3D Land, and am working on the Special world levels now.

I die a lot (the levels are harder!), but I never seem to die enough in a level to have the White Tanooki Leaf appear so I can use the White Tanooki Suit.

Do I need to die more times in the Special Levels? Or does it not appear there? Or am I just not counting how many times I die properly?

Comment: You have to die 5 times to get the tanooki leaf.  Have you died 5 times in one of these special levels?

Comment: @agent86 By my count? Yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of the [Assist Blocks](http://www.mariowiki.com/Assist_Block) appear in the Special Worlds.

Comment: Oh, lovely :( That means the Special Worlds are going to take me approximately forever. :(

Comment: You'll get it though!  It's not much, but I've found that just rushing for the goal with a regular Tanooki suit is just as good. The Assist blocks are only ment to help you get past the main game, with the special levels as extra content for completing the game.

as note: try to skip the challange coins if you see them, they're usually put in places in the extra levels to get you to do something risky.  Come back and get them later when you start to master the tricks they have you do.